# How to pass function as property from one component to another in React

Tags: function, reactjs, properties, components

I am using following code to pass function of one component as a property to another function but getting following error

**cannot read property 'updateComment' of undefined**

This is my code

```
class Board extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            comments:[
                'This is first',
                'This is Second',
                'This is Third'
            ]
        };

        /*this.updateComment = this.updateComment.bind(this);*/
        this.removeComment = this.removeComment.bind(this);
    }



    eachComment(text,i){
        return(
            <Comment key={i} index={i}  update={this.updateComment} remove={this.removeComment}>
                {text}
            </Comment>
        );
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            {
                this.state.comments.map(this.eachComment)
            }
            </div>
        )
    }

    removeComment(i){
        var arr = this.state.comments;
        arr.splice(i,1);
        this.setState({comments:arr});
    }

    updateComment(newText,i){
        var arr = this.state.comments;
        arr[i] = newText;
        this.setState({comments:arr});
    }
}
```

Please let me know whats wrong I am doing.

Comment: You need set this for `.map` callback `this.state.comments.map(this.eachComment, this)`

Comment: @AlexanderT. thanks it worked but what was the hack?? why we passed another this?

Comment: in your example when you use `this.eachComment` - `this` refers to global scope, you need set `this` manually

Answer (score 0):

Your map function `eachComment` doesnt refer to the global scope and hence you wont be able to `updateComment` with the this keyword. You will need to bind this to the global scope

Call the map function like

```
{this.state.comments.map(this.eachComment.bind(this))}
```